# ElasticSearch search for partial alphanumeric values

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram

I have a string field with values like `PA2456U` or `PA23U-RB` and  I would like to do a partial match, so that I can search for `PA24` and I would get the first result, or search `PA23U-RB` and find the second result (so that would be a full match.

I tried using ngram, but it ignores the numeric values, so, if I enter `pa111` it returns anything that starts with `pa`

See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/3803180) for an example.

This may be a separate question, or related, but searching for `12345001` should also match `12345-001`

Thanks

**Update**
The final analyzer I used is here: https://gist.github.com/3803180

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making ngrams looks like a good choice based on your requirements, but I think [edge_ngrams](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/edgengram-tokenfilter.html) should be enough. This way your index would grow a little bit slower since you'd be indexing less terms. Anyway the problem is that you don't need to apply the same analyzer to the query too, otherwise querying for `pa111` would mean querying for all the ngrams that you can make out of it, which would lead you to a lot more matches that you'd expect.

You just need to change your search_analyzer to an analyzer which doesn't make ngrams. You can  use the same you already have and remove the ngram token filter (only for the search_analyzer, the index_analyzer is fine).

Regarding the dash question, have a look at the [Word delimiter token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html). You need to configure it to make it work as you expect. I guess the `generate_number_parts=false`, `generate_word_parts=false` and `split_on_numerics=false` options should make it work as you want. That way the dash won't be indexed. You need to apply the token filter at both index time and query time.

Comment: Thanks you! I got the search of PA2 to match PA2456U, but I cannot get the right syntax for the word_Delimiter, I updated my gist, could you show me how I could add the word_delimiter filter? I keep getting "[failed to find tokenizer type [word_delimiter]"

Comment: I don't see the word_delimiter in your list, but you should do pretty much the same you're doing with ngrams.

Comment: I updated the gist, I added the word_delimiter filter, but when I run the script, I get: "error":"IndexCreationException[[inventory] failed to create index]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Custom Analyzer [part_number_analyzer] failed to find filter under name [part_number_edgeNGram]]; ","status":500}

Comment: ah, I was adding twice the filter tag, but I did not need that, now I don;t get a syntax error, but need to tweak the word delimiter filter. thanks